# Javascript json with key:object

Tags: javascript, json

Why do I have an expected token for my json data 
https://jsfiddle.net/4baLzL4f/

```
    var myArray = [
        "Key1": {
                "field1": "4",
                "field2": "6.62"
            }   
    ,

        "Key2": {
                "field1": "10",
                "field2": "7.62"
            }
];
```

Update : What I need is to easily access by key with something like myArray["Key1"]

Comment: invalid array is why

Answer (score 3):

You may use an [`object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), not an [`array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):

```js
var myObject = {
    "Key1": {
        "field1": "4",
        "field2": "6.62"
    },
    "Key2": {
        "field1": "10",
        "field2": "7.62"
    }
};

document.write(myObject['Key2']['field2'] + '<br>'); // the same 
document.write(myObject.Key2.field2);                // as this
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(myObject, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: What I need is to easily access by key with something like myArray["Key1"]

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to keep your data structure as a `List` of objects:

```
[
  {
    "Key1": {
      "field1": "4",
      "field2": "6.62"
    }
  },
  {
    "Key2": {
      "field1": "10",
      "field2": "7.62"
    }
  }
]
```

As a `Map` of objects:

```
{
  "Key1": {
    "field1": "4",
    "field2": "6.62"
  },
  "Key2": {
    "field1": "10",
    "field2": "7.62"
  }
}
```

Comment: What I need is to easily access by key with something like myArray["Key1"]

Comment: I suggest you go with a map of objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an **array** of **objects** make it like the following.

```
var myArray = [
        {
            "Key1": {
                "field1": "4",
                "field2": "6.62"
            }
        },   
        {
            "Key2": {
                "field1": "10",
                "field2": "7.62"
            }
        }
];
```

If you want to access it **directly with keys** use it as an object (Key/Value pair)

```
var myObj = {
            "Key1": {
                "field1": "4",
                "field2": "6.62"
            },
            "Key2": {
                "field1": "10",
                "field2": "7.62"
            }
        }
```

You can loop through it using **for..in** loop:

```
for (var key in myObj) {
  console.log(myObj[key]);
}
```

Comment: What I need is to easily access by key with something like myArray["Key1"]

Answer (score 0):

```
     var myArray = [
            "Key1": {
                    "field1": "4",
                    "field2": "6.62"
                }   
        ,

            "Key2": {
                    "field1": "10",
                    "field2": "7.62"
                }
    ];

 console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject, 0, 4));
```

Comment: this is not valid json, and parsing on strings

Comment: why? can you please give me hint

Comment: Did you even try what you wrote?

Comment: Sorry,I am doing parse instead of stringify

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
var myArray = [
          {
            "Key1": {
                    "field1": "4",
                    "field2": "6.62"
                }
           },        
           { 
              "Key2": {
                    "field1": "10",
                    "field2": "7.62"
                }
           }
         ];
```

In your example.

```
      var myArray = [

          "Key1": {
                   "field1": "4",
                   "field2": "6.62"
                 }
         ];
```

key **Key1** point to object but this key value pair itself not following true syntax of object.

Object should be like this

```
{
   key : value
}
```

here your *key* is `key1` and value is

```
{
   "field1": "4",
   "field2": "6.62"
}
```

Every key:value inside array should be surrounded by `curly-braces ({})`

Answer (score 0):

Your array is not valid by syntax. Do you have any requirement to access your array elements by both 'key' name and index ? If yes, I think, Nishant's solution is the right option.